# Selenium, python dynamic table

Tags: python, selenium, dynamic-tables

[image]

I'm creating a robot with selenium that get all info from agencies in Brasil, i've alredy done the permutation click between all States and counties, all i have to do now's click in all agencies and get infos like: "telefone","endereço","HORÁRIO DE ATENDIMENTO". How can I do that?? That's my code till now:

```
 # -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
import time     
import urllib
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import request


def make_soup(url):
    thepage = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    soupdata = BeautifulSoup(thepage,'html.parser')
    return soupdata

chrome_path = r"D:\Users\gbenites\Desktop\Inovação\arquivos py\WebDriver\chromedriver.exe"
url = 'http://www2.correios.com.br/sistemas/agencias/'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_path)
driver.get("http://www2.correios.com.br/sistemas/agencias/")
#WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'municipioAgencia')))
driver.maximize_window()


time.sleep(3) 
estadoList = Select(driver.find_element_by_name('estadoAgencia'))
for index in range(3,len(estadoList.options)):
    select = Select(driver.find_element_by_name('estadoAgencia'))
    print("selecting Estado: ",select.options[index].text)    
    print("selecting Index: ",index)    
    select.select_by_index(index)
    time.sleep(2)
    municípioList = Select(driver.find_element_by_name('municipioAgencia'))
    for index_b in range(1,len(municípioList.options)):
        select_b = Select(driver.find_element_by_name('municipioAgencia'))
        print("...selecting Municipio",select_b.options[index_b].text.replace("'",""))
        print("...selecting Municipio Index: ",index_b)
        select_b.select_by_index(index_b)
        time.sleep(3)
        get_info_list =  WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//table[@class = 'dadosAgencia']//td")))
        info_list = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//table[@class = 'dadosAgencia']//span")
        print(range(len(info_list)))
        for record in range(0,len(info_list)):
            print(record.get_attribute('innerText'))
```

And that's my output:

```
selecting Estado:  AMAPÁ
selecting Index:  3
...selecting Municipio AMAPA
...selecting Municipio Index:  1
range(0, 27)
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
15
16
17
18
19
20
21
22
23
24
25
26
```

Comment: Please do not link only image. Edit your question and write in text what do you want.

Comment: Please read why a [screenshot of HTML or code or error is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Consider updating the Question with formatted text based relevant HTML, code trials and error stack trace.

Comment: Sorry guys. It's done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this xPath:

```
//table[@class = 'dadosAgencia']//tr
```

It would be like this:

```
elements = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located(
            (By.XPATH, "//table[@class = 'dadosAgencia']//tr")))
```

it gives you a list of all elements located. To print the text of each element you can use this:

```
for element in elements:
    print(element.text)
```

Note: you have to add some imports:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
```

Comment: that will only get to detalheAgencia 1, not all detalheAgencia[i]

Answer (score 0):

Try this XPath for the table:

```
//table[@class = 'dadosAgencia']
```

First, find table elements:

```
table_elements = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located(
        (By.XPATH, "//table[@class = 'dadosAgencia']")))
```

Iterate through the table:

```
for table_element in table_elements:
    for row in table_element.find_elements_by_xpath(".//tr"):
        print(row.text)
```