# Scraping data from a dynamic web table

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests

I want to scrape data from a webpage with a dynamic table.
The table contains information on train rides.

This is the website:
https://www.laerm-monitoring.de/zug/?mp=3/

I tried to request the data with a simple mounted request session, but I only got basic HTML data without the data from the table.

```
def requests_retry_session(
    retries=3,
    backoff_factor=0.3,
    status_forcelist=(500, 502, 504, 429),
    session=None,
):
    session = session or requests.Session()
    retry = Retry(
        total=retries,
        read=retries,
        connect=retries,
        backoff_factor=backoff_factor,
        status_forcelist=status_forcelist,
    )
    adapter = HTTPAdapter(max_retries=retry)
    session.mount('http://', adapter)
    session.mount('https://', adapter)
    return session 

session = requests_retry_session()
response = session.get('https://www.laerm-monitoring.de/zug/?mp=3/')
response.content
```

How can I do this correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The data is loaded dynamically from different URL. You can use this example how to load it just with `requests`/`beautifulsoup`:

```
import json
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

data = {
    "sort": "Einfahrtzeit-desc",
    "page": "1",
    "pageSize": "10",
    "group": "",
    "filter": "",
    "__RequestVerificationToken": "",
    "locid": "1",
}

headers = {"X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest"}

url = "https://www.laerm-monitoring.de/zug/"
api_url = "https://www.laerm-monitoring.de/zug/train_read"

with requests.Session() as s:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(s.get(url).content, "html.parser")
    data["__RequestVerificationToken"] = soup.select_one(
        '[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]'
    )["value"]
    data = s.post(api_url, data=data, headers=headers).json()

# pretty print the data
print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))
```

Prints:

```json
{
    "Data": [
        {
            "id": 2536954,
            "Einfahrtzeit": "2021-04-24T20:56:26.1703+02:00",
            "Gleis": 1,
            "Richtung": "Kiel",
            "Category": "PZ",
            "Zugkategorie": "Personenzug",
            "Vorbeifahrtdauer": 7.3,
            "Zugl\u00e4nge": 181.85884,
            "Geschwindigkeit": 115.57797,
            "Maximalpegel": 88.611084,
            "Vorbeifahrtpegel": 85.421326,
            "G\u00fcltig": "OK"
        },
        {
            "id": 2536944,
            "Einfahrtzeit": "2021-04-24T20:52:25.1703+02:00",
            "Gleis": 2,
            "Richtung": "Hamburg",
            "Category": "PZ",
            "Zugkategorie": "Personenzug",
            "Vorbeifahrtdauer": 6.3,
            "Zugl\u00e4nge": 211.10226,
            "Geschwindigkeit": 152.60104,
            "Maximalpegel": 91.81743,
            "Vorbeifahrtpegel": 87.95224,
            "G\u00fcltig": "OK"
        },
        {
            "id": 2536929,
            "Einfahrtzeit": "2021-04-24T20:44:31.4703+02:00",
            "Gleis": 1,
            "Richtung": "Kiel",
            "Category": "PZ",
            "Zugkategorie": "Personenzug",
            "Vorbeifahrtdauer": 5.3,
            "Zugl\u00e4nge": 104.69964,
            "Geschwindigkeit": 110.10052,
            "Maximalpegel": 82.100815,
            "Vorbeifahrtpegel": 79.98168,
            "G\u00fcltig": "OK"
        },
        {
            "id": 2536924,
            "Einfahrtzeit": "2021-04-24T20:42:30.3703+02:00",
            "Gleis": 1,
            "Richtung": "Kiel",
            "Category": "PZ",
            "Zugkategorie": "Personenzug",
            "Vorbeifahrtdauer": 2.9,
            "Zugl\u00e4nge": 49.305683,
            "Geschwindigkeit": 125.18,
            "Maximalpegel": 98.63289,
            "Vorbeifahrtpegel": 97.25019,
            "G\u00fcltig": "OK"
        },
        {
            "id": 2536925,
            "Einfahrtzeit": "2021-04-24T20:42:20.5703+02:00",
            "Gleis": 2,
            "Richtung": "Hamburg",
            "Category": "PZ",
            "Zugkategorie": "Personenzug",
            "Vorbeifahrtdauer": 0.0,
            "Zugl\u00e4nge": 0.0,
            "Geschwindigkeit": 0.0,
            "Maximalpegel": 0.0,
            "Vorbeifahrtpegel": 0.0,
            "G\u00fcltig": "-"
        },
        {
            "id": 2536911,
            "Einfahrtzeit": "2021-04-24T20:35:19.3703+02:00",
            "Gleis": 1,
            "Richtung": "Kiel",
            "Category": "PZ",
            "Zugkategorie": "Personenzug",
            "Vorbeifahrtdauer": 4.1,
            "Zugl\u00e4nge": 103.97647,
            "Geschwindigkeit": 132.2034,
            "Maximalpegel": 87.111984,
            "Vorbeifahrtpegel": 85.6776,
            "G\u00fcltig": "OK"
        },
        {
            "id": 2536907,
            "Einfahrtzeit": "2021-04-24T20:33:31.2703+02:00",
            "Gleis": 2,
            "Richtung": "Hamburg",
            "Category": "GZ",
            "Zugkategorie": "G\u00fcterzug",
            "Vorbeifahrtdauer": 23.8,
            "Zugl\u00e4nge": 583.19586,
            "Geschwindigkeit": 95.63598,
            "Maximalpegel": 88.02967,
            "Vorbeifahrtpegel": 85.02115,
            "G\u00fcltig": "OK"
        },
        {
            "id": 2536890,
            "Einfahrtzeit": "2021-04-24T20:25:36.1703+02:00",
            "Gleis": 2,
            "Richtung": "Hamburg",
            "Category": "PZ",
            "Zugkategorie": "Personenzug",
            "Vorbeifahrtdauer": 3.5,
            "Zugl\u00e4nge": 104.63446,
            "Geschwindigkeit": 160.47487,
            "Maximalpegel": 88.60612,
            "Vorbeifahrtpegel": 86.46721,
            "G\u00fcltig": "OK"
        },
        {
            "id": 2536882,
            "Einfahrtzeit": "2021-04-24T20:22:05.8703+02:00",
            "Gleis": 2,
            "Richtung": "Hamburg",
            "Category": "GZ",
            "Zugkategorie": "G\u00fcterzug",
            "Vorbeifahrtdauer": 26.6,
            "Zugl\u00e4nge": 653.52515,
            "Geschwindigkeit": 94.59859,
            "Maximalpegel": 91.9396,
            "Vorbeifahrtpegel": 85.50632,
            "G\u00fcltig": "OK"
        },
        {
            "id": 2536869,
            "Einfahrtzeit": "2021-04-24T20:16:24.3703+02:00",
            "Gleis": 1,
            "Richtung": "Kiel",
            "Category": "PZ",
            "Zugkategorie": "Personenzug",
            "Vorbeifahrtdauer": 3.3,
            "Zugl\u00e4nge": 87.8222,
            "Geschwindigkeit": 160.01207,
            "Maximalpegel": 91.3928,
            "Vorbeifahrtpegel": 89.54336,
            "G\u00fcltig": "OK"
        }
    ],
    "Total": 8657,
    "AggregateResults": null,
    "Errors": null
}
```

Comment: Great answer! A few questions: How did you know what to write into the `data` dictionary and especially, where did you get the `RequestVerificationToken`? Where did you get the `api_url` from? Why do you need a post request here? If these questions are too much, can recommend a good ressource to read up on these things? Thank you!

Comment: @gython All the information I saw in Firefox developer tools->Network tab (there are all requests that the page is doing, among them one with this data). The `__RequestVerificationToken` was contained within the original page (I did Ctrl+F and marked the place where it is)

Answer (score 3):

With a simple GET request you can retrieve the HTML of the *landing page*.

```py
import requests

response = requests.get('https://www.laerm-monitoring.de/zug/')  # even without query-parameters: ?mp=3/
print( response.content )
```

#### Analyze the dynamic requests (browser)

This can also be done in any browser.
In the *source view* (in Win/Linux: CRTL + U or in Mac: CMD + U) you will find the token needed for all subsequent requests against the REST API: `__RequestVerificationToken`.

It's inside a **hidden** `<input>` form-field one this page:

```html
<input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" value="CfDJ8B_eKmsiQC9Esc7ZjyC063dp6MzAtP3Sawnrfz3SCqxOMoPCYMV4sjDbrhDbuOsPcLnOiElgqQWTdMxCgfmhNVx1eC6oR81kZT3os2z3DJxtu6H9V7fKt9z9bdSJwB1ACYSSYWHsmPzt-AMWvSk4eYU" />
```

When the page loads in your browser this *token* will be used to load the data dynamically (as you already assumed) via *JavaScript* [`XMLHttpRequest`s (XHR)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMLHttpRequest).

To view these *XHR requests* open the **Network tab** of your browser's developer tools window (shortcut F12):

- Chrome: [Inspect network activity](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/network/)
- Firefox: [Network Monitor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Network_Monitor)

[image: browsers dev-tools network tab shows 2 XHR requests]

Both requests are fetching the measured data as JSON. For security reasons the called web API requires a token which is sent using a POST request. It's submitted in the body as `x-www-form-urlencoded` along with the *pagination* parameters.

See following example from the command-line via [cURL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CURL):

```sh
curl -vi 'https://www.laerm-monitoring.de/zug/train_read' -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8' --data-raw 'sort=Einfahrtzeitdesc&page=1&pageSize=10&group=&filter=&__RequestVerificationToken=CfDJ8...
```

(token was shortened for illustration purpose)

**Hint**: in the browser's *Network tab* you can usually right-click on the request to [copy as CURL](https://everything.curl.dev/usingcurl/copyas) command.

Answer (score 1):

I have used Selenium to do something similar with python. Not sure if that works for your. Basically open the website and right click on table and do `inspect element`. After that Go over to the `div` that the table belongs to and `right-click` to copy `full xpath`. After you found the xpath, you can **scrape** it using selenium. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51273995/selenium-python-dynamic-table) .

The only problem is that Selenium actually opens the browser and doesn't run in background. I think you can do it silently, but I have never done it.

Another thing is that websites can block you if repeated automated requests come from a single IP. You can use tor to make request from a new IP every time you make a request. I have done something like that [with twitter here](https://github.com/aditya18007/Tilly).